# parse add multiple images to an array after loop

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift, parse-platform

I have an item Object which has a relation class which contain several images related to the item. The problem is I'm trying to add these images to an array so first inside the loop I'm adding them to one array and after the loop I'm adding them to the image Array and then when the loop is completed I want to reload table View. At the moment it seems like

```
Self.imageArray.addObject(imageDic)
```

is being called before the loop and therefor nothing is added to the array.

How can I do this?

```
                var relation = itemObject.relationForKey("file") as PFRelation
                var imageQuery = relation.query() as PFQuery
                imageQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageObj: [AnyObject]!, error1: NSError!) -> Void in
                    if error1 == nil {

                        var imageDic = NSMutableArray()

                        for obj in imageObj {

                            var imageObject = obj as PFObject
                            var thumbnail = imageObject.objectForKey("file") as PFFile


                            thumbnail.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                                (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                                if error == nil {
                                    let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                                    imageDic.addObject(image)




                                }
                            }

                        }
                        self.imageArray?.addObject(imageDic)
                        println(self.imageArray?.count)




                    }


                }


               self.tableView?.reloadData()
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the block is called afterwards and your self.tableView?.reloadData() would be called before anything is added to it.

So I made cahnges in your code as below:-

```
    var relation = itemObject.relationForKey("file") as PFRelation
    var imageQuery = relation.query() as PFQuery
    imageQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageObj: [AnyObject]!, error1: NSError!) -> Void in
       if error1 == nil {

           var imageDic = NSMutableArray()

           for obj in imageObj {

              var imageObject = obj as PFObject
              var thumbnail = imageObject.objectForKey("file") as PFFile

              thumbnail.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                 (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                         let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                         //    imageDic.addObject(image)  //No need of this array.

                         self.imageArray?.addObject(imageDic)
                         println(self.imageArray?.count)   //simply add object into this array.
                       }
                    }
                 }   
             self.tableView?.reload() 
              }
          }
      }
```

Comment: cannot invoke getData with an argument of type nsdata

Comment: What is the flow of your app? As this is kinda messy bcoz your having a background task inside another background task.

Comment: Also check if you get scope of imageObj in block of getDataInBackground.